# I need to access a column inside of a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two models- Student and Teacher. There is a many to many relationship established between the students and the teachers. A Student has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers. And a Teacher has_and_belongs_to_many :students. To create the migration, I ran:

```
rails g migration create_students_teachers student:references teacher:references request_status:boolean
```

This is what the migration looks like (I added a default value of false):

```
class CreateStudentsTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students_teachers do |t|
      t.boolean :request_status, :default => false
      t.references :teacher, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :student, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Currently, a student can browse through all of the teachers, and choose a teacher that matches their personal needs. Once the student clicks on a teacher, it will associate that student with the clicked teacher. In the view, I iterate through each teacher like so (@teachers = Teacher.all):

```
<% @teachers.each do |teacher| %>
  <%= link_to "#{teacher.teacher_profile.name}", request_path(teacher.id), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

And then in the requests controller, my update method looks like this:

```
def update
  @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  current_student.teachers << @teacher
end
```

This code works, however, now I want to render each student associated with a teacher, in which has a request status of false (pending requests).

When I try to run:

```
Pending requests:

<% current_teacher.students.each do |student| %>
  <% if student.request_status = false %>
    <%= student.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I get a no method error because of course the request_status is an unknown method to the student due to the fact that it is in a join table. I want to all of a teacher's students rendered only if the relationship set up in the join table has a value of false in the request status column. I hope this makes sense, and if it doesn't please ask, and I will further clarify.

I looked for a an answer for a long time and couldn't seem to find anyone with the same problem. I've tried many different things, and would not waste someone's time if I thought I could find the answer elsewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model that represents your association.

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutorings
  has_many :students, through: :tutoring
end

class Tutoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutorings
  has_many :teachers, through: :tutoring
end
```

Then, you will have access to `request_status` field. Read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Comment: Ahhh- yeah. That makes more sense. So your saying I need a join model called tutoring, that associates teachers and students, and has a column with request_status. But when rendering the students, how would I filter for only the ones with a request_status of false in the join table?

Comment: Just join models and use where clause for filtering out required records. `Student.joins(:tutorings).joins(:teacherss).where("teachers.id" => teacher_id)`. Please try to run it in your rails console and see if it is behaving correctly. You might want to add `.uniq` at the end as well.